# Which numpy operations copy and which mutate?

Tags: numpy

Is there a general rule of thumb for knowing which operations on a `numpy.ndarray` produce a *copy* of the values and which mutate them in-place?

I'm pretty new to numpy and I'm sure I'll learn the hard way eventually, but I was wondering if there were general principles driving mutability that might help speed my learning.

Comment: There aren't many true inplace numpy operations Only ones I can think of are direct shape assignment, an inplace sort, resize, += style math, and indexed assignment..

Comment: No obvious rule of thumb, but the list of mutators is short. I think I have pretty much the full list in my answer, so just consult back here if ever confused, I guess?

Comment: @tel I think the rule of thumb for me is "almost never mutates" and also "almost always returns a view", which is very helpful for me here starting out. The underlying concern is avoiding inadvertently changing something I want to treat as immutable (because other methods will use it too) and avoiding unnecessary performance penalties. I hadn't made the view vs. copy distinction before your answer, so that is also a very useful insight :) As I take it, an array is like a map into a "base", and it's lightweight to make a new map on an existing base, which is essentially what creating a view is.

Comment: Pretty much. The only thing I'd add is that some arrays are "bases", in the sense that they have formal ownership of their underlying memory buffer. Thankfully, whether or not an array owns its own data makes almost no difference in the vast majority of cases (though, another rule of thumb: operations on arrays that own their own data are "more likely" to return a view rather than a copy (though there's also plenty of cases when an op on a view will indeed return a view)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Functions that mutate in place

Relatively few numpy functions mutate in place. For the most part, numpy functions return array views when they can, and copies when they can't.

Here's an exhaustive list (trawled from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.4/numpy-user-1.15.4.pdf)) of functions/methods that mutate in place:

- `ndarray.resize`
- `ndarray.sort`
- All of the in-place binary operators (eg `+=`, `*=`, `^=`, etc)
- `numpy.fill_diagonal`
- `numpy.random.shuffle`
- `ndarray.partition`

and here's a list of the functions/methods that can optionally mutate in place:

- `ndarray.byteswap`
- `numpy.nan_to_num`

Certain assignments will also mutate an array in place. You can change the values in an array by assigning to a slice (eg `arr[...] = 1` will set every value in an array to `1`), and you can reshape an array by assigning a new shape directly to `.shape`, eg `arr.shape = (2,3)` (won't always work, see notes [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape)).

There's also some functions that support an `out` keyword arg. These functions will behave as mutators if you pass the same array as both input and `out`.

Fair warning, I may have missed one or two mutators that weren't clearly marked in the docs. In any case, the list is short, so there's not much to memorize.

#### Notes on view vs copy return values

One of the goals of the numpy devs over the last few years seemingly has been to make it more common for the numpy functions and the `ndarray` methods to return views instead of copies. At this point, it's reasonably safe to assume that if a numpy function/method *can* return a view, it will do so by default.

For example, `ndarray.flatten` and `ndarray.ravel` do the same thing (returned a flattened array). However, the [docs for `ndarray.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten) explicitly say that it will return a copy, whereas the [docs for `ndarray.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html#numpy-ndarray-ravel) say that it will return a copy only if absolutely necessary.

In live code, as a rule of thumb you can always check if an operation produced a view or a copy by comparing the `id` of the `.base` of your result to the `id` of original array. For example:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2],
                [3, 4],
                [5, 6]])

arrflat = arr.flatten()
assert arrflat.base is not arr

arrravel = arr.ravel()
assert arrravel.base is arr
```

Comment: I'm not sure he's asking about views vs. copies.  Both are new array objects.